# ScrollPane functions for AS3 are missing

Tags: actionscript-3

I have recently discovered that my ScrollPane class code hinting is completely missing. Nevertheless, some basic functions such as setStyle and source can be found in item list, and are still working. The problem starts when trying to customize the ScrollPane with such functions as horizontalScrollPolicy, at which point the compiler returns an error such as 'call to a possibly undefined method'. Help >_<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out after some time. It appears that the code snippet that is being used throughout various sources does not work. Instead I use `myScrollPane.horizontalScrollPolicy = "on";`